# Drawing a chart from a datatable

Tags: c#, charts, datatable

I am trying to draw a graph with multiple series on it. the data for it comes from a database through a `DataAdapter` into a `DataTable`, like this;

```
public DataTable deaths_per_reason_per_year(string farmerid)
 {
     dt = new DataTable();
     try
     {
         conn.Open();  // (select formatted to fit SO lines)
         SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT DATEPART(yyyy, DeathDate) AS 'Year',   
              Reason,   
              COUNT(DeathID) AS 'Number of Deaths' FROM [Farmstat_V1.0].[dbo].[Death] 
              WHERE FarmerID = '" + farmerid + "' 
              GROUP BY  Reason, YEAR(DeathDate);", conn);
         SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
         dt.Load(reader);
     }
     catch (Exception)
     {
         throw;
     }
     finally
     {
         conn.Close();
     }
     return dt;
 }
```

This gives me the following output;

[image: DataTable with the sql output]

When I try to assign the DataTable to my chart on the form, with this;

```
StatsDataAccess sda = new StatsDataAccess();

chart1.DataSource = sda.deaths_per_reason_per_year(FarmerID);
chart1.Series["Series1"].XValueMember = "Year";
chart1.Series["Series1"].YValueMembers = "Number of Deaths";
chart1.Series["Series2"].XValueMember = "Reason";
chart1.Series["Series2"].YValueMembers = "Number of Deaths";
chart1.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisX.MajorGrid.Enabled = false;
chart1.Series["Series1"].IsValueShownAsLabel = true;
chart1.DataBind();
```

I get a drawn graph that looks like this, I have added the series in there through the properties pane of the chart;

[image: output]

But I want an output that should look like this;

[image: actual output]

I've tried googleing without success. Can somebody please help me with this?
I'll appreciate it very much.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most visible problem is all about the data type of the x-Values.

All X-Values are internally of type `double`.

**Introduction**

- If if you add `DataPoints` with numbers in the X-Values they are treated and stored as expected
- If you add `DataPoints` with `DateTime` X-Values they are converted to double as well (via OLE Automation Date conversion)

But if you add types that can't be converted to a number, like strings, things get weird. **Internally** the X-Values are all `0`, because what else could they be but the **labels display** the strings.

The displayed `DataPoints` are treated as if the had X-Values of 0,1,2,3... and the points are shown with nice and equal spacing.

To many many newbies this looks fine and they never know that they have effectively **lost** the X-Values.

Their problems come when the try to use number formatting or try to calculate with the X-Values.

**Your problem**

Your 'problem' is that your `select` delivers integers from the `DATEPART` function, so you did it right, in fact you did it too well to work out f the box..

It sounds perfectly fine **and it is**..

..however the `Chart` tries to display many items with `Auto` settings and while they **usually** work fine, here they don't because they try to start the chart at `x = 0` and of course the three actual values of `2014-2016` get squeezed to the right beyond recognition.

The solution is simple: Set the display minimum:

```
chart1.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisX.Minimum = 2014;
```

and all is well. You may want to calculate that value from the x-Values in your `Points`, and, hooray, you can, because you have them..

This is the best way, as long as your series has meaningful numbers for X-Values.

Unfortunately the second series doesn't seem to have that..

The ugly alternative would be to convert the year to a string, but, don't do that unless you really must!

After fixing the scaling problem the other big issue of your code gets visible:

**Your data mapping is wrong.**

Comparing the data table and the desired output, your data binding simply won't map to a chart like that.

Solution: You should **split** the data into as many separate sources as you have `reasons`, i.e. as you have `Series` to bind.

I would create a separate `DataViews` for each `reason`, each based on the same `DataTable` but with a different `Filter` (reason = 'reason1'..) and then bind each `DataView` to one `Series`.

Off the top of my head this is how it could look like:

```
DataTable DT = yourTable;

DataView dv1 = new DataView(DT);
DataView dv2 = new DataView(DT);
..
dv1.RowFilter = "reason=='Sold'";
dv2.RowFilter = "reason=='Other'";
..
yourSeries1.Points.DataBind(dv1, "year", "deathcount", "");
..
```

Now all `Series DataPoints` are bound the same way, all `Series` show and the scaling is fixed.

Comment: I did what you said, but this is the new results; [link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B-t1PtUkARFPeGMyWHQzdzg0ZXc)

Comment: I don't have a google drive password. please use a freely accessible site or add it to the question!

Comment: Sorry, my bad. Try [this](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-t1PtUkARFPeGMyWHQzdzg0ZXc/view?usp=sharing) one.

Comment: Well that is a little better, isn't it. But Series 2 is missing. I guess the simplest solution is to go for the usgly alternative; I'll update the answer.

Comment: Please take not of the output how I want it to be, the Year on the x-axes and the reasons as the different colors or Series. So I guess I need 4 series on the graph. Like the last image in my question

Comment: Indeed. I wonder if your data are not rather wrong anyway, have a look at the suggested fix!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94507/discussion-between-taw-and-mentos93).

Comment: No need to continue in chat. It works! I split up the DataTable into DataViews like you said, and I add the line `chart1.Series["Illness"].Points.DataBind(dv1, "Year", "Number of Deaths", "");` for all four DataViews and it worked! Thank you very much for your help and time!