# C# winform & SQL Create line chart "Query and binding"

Tags: c#, sql, winforms, charts

I have a table in SQLserver with some values as following

```
+----------+------+-------+-------+-----+--------+
| MonTime  | Temp | Steam | Water | Air | Vacuum |
+----------+------+-------+-------+-----+--------+
| 16:08:08 |    0 |    38 |    57 |  76 |     95 |
| 16:09:08 |    9 |    28 |    47 |  66 |     85 |
| 16:10:08 |   18 |    37 |    56 |  76 |     95 |
| 16:11:08 |    9 |    28 |    47 |  66 |     85 |
| 16:12:08 |    9 |    28 |    47 |  66 |     85 |
| 16:13:08 |   18 |    37 |    56 |  75 |     94 |
| 16:14:08 |    9 |    28 |    47 |  66 |     85 |
+----------+------+-------+-------+-----+--------+
```

I need to create a line chart in winform application. where x is timeline "MonTime" and y is values and a line for each col "Temp, Steam, Water, etc"
I don't know how to accomplish this. Any help??

Comment: What part you dont know? Connect to db, create a query. read the result, show the chart?

Comment: Show us db schema, sample data and expected output. 
 Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

Comment: the query. I don't know how to convert "MonTime" values to columns to be used as X for the chart.

Comment: You can use MonTime as X, what is the problem you want some groups?

Comment: Line chart will display values for temp , steam and water over a timeline. where  each MonTime value will be a point in the time line X and it will has a value in the Y .

Comment: Use the Chart control from tha Data pane. Bind the Points of a Series. Done. [See here for a discussion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33588055/drawing-a-chart-from-a-datatable/33588458#33588458)

Comment: Thanks for your support. The problem was with the MonTime datatype "Time(0)" this datatype is not supported by Chart control . I converted it to datetime in SQL and then set it up as Time in chart control X value type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your support. The problem was with the MonTime datatype "Time(0)" this datatype is not supported by Chart control . I converted it to datetime in SQL and then set it up as Time in chart control X value type.